# jQuery Countdown plugin break on IE and Safari

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, countdown

I'm using [jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) with multiple instances on one page

```
<div class="TimeLeft">
    <?php echo counterDate($dl['end'][0]); //YYYY, MM, DD ?>
</div>
<div class="TimeLeft">
    <?php echo counterDate($dl['end'][1]); //YYYY, MM, DD ?>
</div>
```

and etc...

my jquery code use each function

```
$(".TimeLeft").each(function() {
        $(this).countdown({until:  new Date($(this).text()) , format: 'HMS', compact: true, 
    layout: '<span class="offerTimeStart">&nbsp;</span><span class="offerTimeContent">{hnn}</span><span class="offerTimeSep">&nbsp;</span><span class="offerTimeContent">{mnn}</span><span class="offerTimeSep">&nbsp;</span><span class="offerTimeContent">{snn}</span><span class="offerTimeEnd">&nbsp;</span>', serverSync: serverTime});
    });
```

All work perfect in Firefox and Chrome - plugin return correct hours until end date but IE and Safari shows just Nan Nan Nan

I try to use different time format such a Date and Hour but no success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to date in jQuery and Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052660/convert-string-to-date-in-jquery-and-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use DateRegex for "that thing" called IE :

[Convert string to date in jQuery and Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052660/convert-string-to-date-in-jquery-and-internet-explorer)

I hope this link will be helpful for you.

I don't know what solution about Safari, but try use IE way.