# Date format not working in IE7

Tags: javascript

I just want timestamps for comparing two dates but it does not convert strings to dated. I tried this code:

```
var a_date = new Date('2013-03-25');
var b_date = new Date('25-03-2013');
alert(a_date + '***' + b_date);
```

I tried it on both Firefox and IE7. Date `a_date` works in Firefox but does not work in IE7 (it gives `Invalid Date` value) and `b_date` works on IE7 but not in Firefox (it gives `NaN` value). Any way to use only one date format to run both?

Comment: `new Date(2013, 2, 25)` works across browsers.

Comment: but my string in textbox is in this formate `2013-03-25` how i convert `2013-03-25` string to `2013, 3, 25` formate ?

Comment: `var parts = '2013-03-25'.split('-'); new Date( parseInt( parts[0], 10 ), parseInt( parts[1], 10 ) - 1, parseInt( parts[2], 10 ) );`

Comment: split it using '-' and concat it by using ','

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working by i do this code :

```
var a_date = document.getElementById('Date_From').value;
var parts1 = a_date.split('-'); 
var b_date = document.getElementById('Date_To').value;
var parts2 = b_date.split('-');

var a_date_1 = new Date( parseInt( parts1[0], 10 ), parseInt( parts1[1], 10 ) - 1, parseInt( parts1[2], 10 ) );
var a_date_2 = new Date( parseInt( parts2[0], 10 ), parseInt( parts2[1], 10 ) - 1, parseInt( parts2[2], 10 ) );
       var date1 = a_date_1.getTime();
       var date2 = a_date_2.getTime();

   if(date1 <= date2) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

special thanks to @Salman A and @Juhana

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways of instantiating a date (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

For other formats you have to write your own convertors. See [Convert string to date in jQuery and Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052660/convert-string-to-date-in-jquery-and-internet-explorer) for example

Answer (score 0):

It is the [definition of the Date object](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to use values 0-11 for the month field.

I believe that the constructor using a String is system-dependent (not to mention locale/timezone dependent) so you are probably better off using the constructor where you specify year/month/day as seperate parameters.

BTW, in Firefox,

```
new Date("04/02/2008");
```

works fine for me - it will interpret slashes, but not hyphens. I think this proves my point that using a String to construct a Date object is problemsome. Use explicit values for month/day/year instead:

```
 new Date(2008, 3, 2);
```