# javascript date() not work with IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, date-conversion

Converting this format date

> "2014, 6, 2"

not work with IE
Example:

```
 var date = "2014, 6, 2";
 console.log(new Date(date));
```

IE return invalid date
any idea please

Comment: can you post the invalid date you are getting in IE ? are you sure you are facing this issue only in IE?

Comment: yes it is only in IE, chrome and firefox are ok. and IE did't return date it return "[date] Invalid Date"

Comment: What about regular expression like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052660/convert-string-to-date-in-jquery-and-internet-explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing Date is not implemented the same across browsers.

Either you (pre)parse/format it by yourself or maybe you can try something like http://momentjs.com/

More detailed - EcmaScript5 Spec states:

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based 
>     upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 
>      Extended Format. The format is as follows: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
>
> [...]
>
> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to 
>      the rules called out in Time String Format (15.9.1.15) [above paragraph]. 
>      If the String does not conform to that format **the function may fall back to any 
>      implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats**.

Comment: thanks, I parse the date format from "2014, 6, 2" to "6/2/2014" and now it works in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

**[workingfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/78E4Q/2/)**

Testing on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
var d = new Date("16 Jan 2014 10:56:24 am PST");
console.log(d);
```

good luck!